# Why isn't timespec_get defined on any C compiler on my Mac?

Tags: c, time, c11, timespec

According to the C11 Standard (7.27.2.5), there is a function `timespec_get` specified in `time.h`.  I have tried several compilers, including clang and several versions of gcc, which are supposed to support C11, but this function is always missing.  The macro `TIME_UTC` is also missing.

Here is a test file `mytime.c`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("C version: %ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
  fflush(stdout);
  struct timespec ts;
  timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
}
```

and the output using Clang:

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ cc -std=c11 mytime.c
mytime.c:9:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'timespec_get' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
  ^
mytime.c:9:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TIME_UTC'
  timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
                    ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I commented out the `timespec_get` line just to make sure I am using C11, and I am.

I get basically the same results for gcc versions 4.8, 5, and 6.

I am using a Mac, OS 10.11.6.

Comment: Functions are defined in libraries, not compilers. Maybe the OS X libraries simply don't support that function?

Comment: FWIW, gcc and clang on my Mac don't support it, either.  I use `gettimeofday` to get sub-second time.  (The Mac doesn't support Posix `clock_gettime`, either.)  There are also some [Darwin-specific clock functions](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/clock_get_time.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mac OS X standard library does not conform to any modern version of C or POSIX. It is stuck at C99 and POSIX 2001 and has conformance problems even with respect to these.

Comment: The OP should note that modern C compilers are pretty much a Linux thing.  On windows, MSVC is a weird hybrid of C89 and a few bits and pieces borrowed from later specs.  If you ever want your C code to be portable, you pretty much want to stick with C89 features, as painful as that is.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: I think that's a misrepresentation and muddles the *library* issue (which this question is about) with a compiler issue (MSVC is junk). Compiler-side there is C99 & C11 support for basically every platform of modern relevance (GCC and clang/llvm support almost everything) and modern MSVC even *kinda* aims to support modern standards (they claim modern C++; modern C is less reliable).

Comment: Hmm.  I suppose it was careless to say "compiler" rather than "language implementation" which was the intent.  (Particularly given that the content of `time.h` is part of the C specification.)   I don't think it's consistent with the notion of "portability" to say "it's portable so long as you have GCC on your platform", but that's not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: So Apple is preventing me from having a conforming C11 implementation?  Does anyone know why?  All the money in the world, and they can't implement `timespec_get`?

Comment: @SteveSiegel: In principle you could use an alternate implementation of the standard library, but that would be potentially incompatible with the whole library ecosystem and AFAIK none for OSX exist. Alternatively you could add a secondary library with these functions and patch the standard headers to add the necessary declarations, etc. (or add a directory of overlay headers to the beginning of the include path and have them use the nonstandard `#include_next` feature) to get the missing C11 library functionality.

Comment: Do you mean all the stuff I install with `brew install` avoids this function? I don't believe it. It must be some configuration option and I don't see why this answer is accepted. My clang is 1001 and have this problem while the online compiler "coliru" has clang 5 and compiles the code without an issue.

Comment: Yes. I've never seen any real world code use this function because it's a less functional clone of the POSIX `clock_gettime`.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS 10.15 supports `timespec_get`. This is taken from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/time.h`:

```c
#if (__DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL) && \
        ((defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L) || \
        (defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201703L))
/* ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.27.2.5 The timespec_get function */
#define TIME_UTC        1       /* time elapsed since epoch */
__API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.15), ios(13.0), tvos(13.0), watchos(6.0))
int timespec_get(struct timespec *ts, int base);
#endif
```

You need to be building with C11 or C++17 or newer when `time.h` is included.

I have not done any timing or other investigation into whether `gettimeofday` or `timespec_get` is better for this purpose on Mac 10.15, only that `timespec_get` becomes available.